# VB script InStr returning later instance of string

Tags: vbscript

I have a script that is supposed to find the number of pages in a PDF document. In some cases, it is finding this incorrectly, and I'm looking at it and finding something puzzling: InStr isn't returning the first instance of my string, but one in the middle. Here is some code:

```
    Set TempFile = fso.OpenTextFile(sFileName, 1)
    lNumPages = 0
    sLine = TempFile.ReadAll
    Temp = InStr(sLine, "/Count ")
    'Strip out the number of pages
    lNumPages = CLng(Mid(sLine, Temp + 7, InStr(Temp + 1, sLine, "/") - Temp - 7))
```

Using a text editor (Textpad in this case) I can see the following in the file itself when I search for "/Count ":

```
515 0 obj
<<
/Count 13
/Kids [ 516 0 R 520 0 R 525 0 R 528 0 R
532 0 R 535 0 R 539 0 R ]
/Type /Pages
>>
endobj

516 0 obj
<<
/Count 2
/Kids [ 517 0 R ]
/Parent 515 0 R
/Type /Pages
>>
endobj

517 0 obj
<<
/Count 2
/Kids [ 518 0 R 519 0 R ]
/Parent 516 0 R
/Type /Pages
>>
endobj
```

down to

```
522 0 obj
<<
/Count 1
/Kids [ 53 0 R ]
/Parent 521 0 R
/Type /Pages
>>
endobj

523 0 obj
<<
/Count 1
/Kids [ 97 0 R ]
/Parent 521 0 R
/Type /Pages
>>
endobj

524 0 obj
<<
/Count 1
/Kids [ 136 0 R ]
/Parent 521 0 R
/Type /Pages
>>
endobj

525 0 obj
<<
/Count 1
/Kids [ 526 0 R ]
/Parent 515 0 R
/Type /Pages
>>
endobj
```

and more. The issue is that the `Temp = InStr(sLine, "/Count ")` line sets Temp to the position for /Count following the 522 object, instead of the first instance, the 515 object, which all text editors find.

I even did a hex comparison, and find them all to be the same, with the following characters: 43 6F 75 6E 74 20 31 33

What could possibly be causing InStr to locate a string that is neither first nor last?

The file is about 532k, but the first character found with InStr is at position 532,584, so not really close to 524,288, either, if it would make any difference.

Comment: What happens if you output `sLine`?  Does it look like you expect?  Have you tried specifying a starting position for `inStr`?  `Temp = InStr(0,sLine, "/Count ")`

Comment: The beginning of sLine does indeed match the beginning of the file in text editors, which is what I expect.

I have not tried specifying a starting position, because I have no idea where the starting position might be, and I always want the first occurrence.

EDIT: I guess you have to use Shift to get new lines.

Comment: I ran this with your sample text and `Temp = 16` and `lNumPages = 13`.  This seems correct.

Comment: Thank you for trying it. I can't feasibly include the whole file, though, and more than 500k comes before the actual sample. It starts with this: %PDF-1.5

544 0 obj
<<
/E 114871
/H [ 2813 445 ]
/L 545470
/Linearized 1
/N 13
/O 547
/T 534538
>>                                                                
endobj

xref
544 89

Comment: If it's not sensitive data you could put it on pastebin

Comment: Unfortunately it does have sensitive information.

Comment: I may have mis-understood but you are reading in an entire file to a `string` then trying to use `InStr()` to identify position of a particular occurrence of the value `/Count`? In which case the start should always be position `1` as [`InStr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c(v=vs.84).aspx) starts from position `1` not position `0` *(as @DevilsAdvocate suggests)*. If you omit it, it will begin from `1` anyway. Personally this method is very inefficient and likely full of pitfalls *(as you are experiencing)*, I would suggest trying to read line by line instead for a start.

Comment: One more suggest try not to see it as `InStr()` behaving weirdly it's more likely that something you are doing in the code is causing the weird behaviour. Always worth approaching it like that so you don't make assumptions that will later come back to bite you.

Comment: Although this isn't Classic ASP this example might be of some benefit - [Efficiently Reading Large Text Files](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/010401-1.shtml)

Comment: Yes, I'm reading the entire file into a string to search for /Count. I'm not asking for a start position, so it should start at the first character. When I originally wrote this, I tried using a read-line approach, and couldn't get it to work. I haven't cut out any of the pertinent code, but show I'm assigning the stream to a string variable. If the file size gets much larger then I might have some issues, but I'm still puzzled by how InStr seems to find a random instance of /Count.

Comment: Is it possible that the `Temp` position is just too large to fit inside an [`Integer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf(v=vs.84).aspx) *(range -32,768 to 32,767)* ? `InStr()` returns a long so try using `CLng()` *(range -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647)* around any `InStr()` call.

Comment: Remember in memory it is Unicode. So When you read the ANSI file codepage conversion happens. What are the various codepage settings of computer and file.

Comment: @Lankymart It is too large for an Int, but CLng doesn't help (just tested it). SELECT TOP 1 itemnum FROM hsi.itemdata. When looking at the data in hex, it looks the same. I still have no explanation for which particular instance of /Count in the file it finds first, though it is the 8th every time.

Comment: I finally got a chance to try reading it line by line, and though my new application works, it is decidedly odd. For example, one line that has "/Count" in it reads like this (surrounded by brackets): [-½ŒŽuþä…¤³!EË>ß¬]%„ÅÅñÙ­qü *¶ýjÀÍÕkÏ˜hõIâ'²Î!Ý×*sÖýjÉŸÑRÁà]'òYÿ] Notepad++ doesn't say /Count is in it, nor do I see anything else that can qualify. I'm left determining if the string actually contains a number (IsNumeric), and if so, assume it is the page number. Thank you to everyone for your comments.